# NullableAttribute prensent over a non-Nullable string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm using the code below to detect nullable reference types. It worked fine so far, but today I encountered a situation where it doesn't work as expected.

Why Is the compiler placing `[Nullable]` on `PartnerId` in the class below?
And why is it gone when I comment out the Dummy  property ?

```
#nullable enable


using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace NullableStrange
{
    public class Test1
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string PartnerId { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? Dummy { get; set; } // comment out 
        public Test1? PartnerLegal { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type t = typeof(Test1);
            var partnerId = t.GetProperty("PartnerId");

            // I would expect false, but it's true
            Console.WriteLine(IsNullableReferenceType(partnerId));
        }

        static bool IsNullableReferenceType(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            return propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes()
                .Any(a => a.GetType().Name == "NullableAttribute");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your approach to detecting this is too simplistic. See the duplicate for the correct approach (and background info).

Comment: See the linked question. The compiler puts `NullableContext` on the type to set the default nullability for all members of that type, then overrides that for the other members using specific `Nullable` attributes

Comment: @JeroenMostert almost thought so ;-) thanks for the link.